# How can I change a gameobject in the hierarchy material to another material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var newmat = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Materials/Univeral Render Pipeline Lit.mat", typeof(Material));

        object[] obj = FindObjectsOfType<Material>();
        var allob = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach(object objs in obj)
        {
            var mat = (Material)objs;
            if (mat.name.StartsWith("Default"))
            {
                defaultMaterials.Add((Material)objs);  
            }
        }
```

I want to assign the newmat with mat.
The problem is that it's just materials and not the gameobjects of this materials.

This line will find all the gameobjects :

```
var allob = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
```

but there are over 5000 gameobjects and loop over all of them might be slow.
also there is only two gameobjects with this Default material that I want to change.

should I loop over all the gameobjects get each one material and find for the Defaults ones and then make the switch or there is a way to do it only with the materials ?

Comment: Tag your default materials  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Jeff said: tagging your GameObjects, you can also:

1. If your GameObjects are not dynamically created, you can assign them to an array property in a MonoBehaviour script and access them.
2. If your GameObjects are dynamically created and you know which ones will have the default material, you can add them to an array while creating them and later access them.